# IE incompatibility banner

Tags: internet-explorer, redirect, microsoft-edge, banner, incompatibility

Is it possible to have the same banner as on [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jIEw1.png) when users search for my website in IE ? As example, search for apple. However it doesn't work when I search for my website. How to let browser know to open my website in the newest MS Edge browser ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try to search but did not get any way to show this same banner with a specific site.

As a workaround, you can try to use Javascript code to identify the IE browser and display your custom message on your own site.

Example:

```js
function Detect_IE() {
           var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
         
           var msie = ua.indexOf('MSIE ');
           if (msie > 0) {
            
             return "IE " + parseInt( ua.substring(msie + 5, ua.indexOf('.', msie)), 10);
           }
         
           var trident = ua.indexOf('Trident/');
           if (trident > 0) {
            
             var rv = ua.indexOf('rv:');
             return "IE " + parseInt(ua.substring(rv + 3, ua.indexOf('.', rv)), 10);
           }

           // other browser
           return "false";
         }
         var result=Detect_IE();
         if (result=="false")
         {
            document.getElementById("info").innerHTML +="<h2>Welcome to the site...</h2>";
         }
         else
         {
            document.getElementById("info").innerHTML += "<h2>Dear user you are using " + result + " This browser is outdated and not supported by this site. Kindly use supported browser...</h2>";
         }
```

```html
<div id="info"></div><br>
<h2>Test Page...</h2>
```

Output in the IE 11:

[image]

Note that this code will work from IE 7 to IE 11 versions.

If it is an IE browser then it will show the above message else it will display welcome text.

Further, you can modify the sample code as per your own requirements.

Comment: If you think it can work for you then you can consider accepting the answer.

Comment: I am still curious about the way it detects that website is incompatible with IE. Any ideas by what criteria it does so ?

Comment: Based on my search result, It looks like Bing is maintaining some kind of list and show the banner for those sites that are on the list. you can notice that other search engines are not displaying this kind of banner. Users of the site can use any search engine for searching your site. so it is better to show the message on your own site.

Comment: Thank you for your watchfulness! I guess now it's clear that the modal is the most viable solution here

Comment: @Arhacktector, let us know if you have further questions regarding this issue. Thanks for your understanding.